# What's the equivalent syntax in MySQL for `with xxx AS ()`

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

In MSSQL, I have a query something like:

```
WITH temp AS (
SELECT
    *
FROM
  xx.xxxx
)
```

But `WITH temp AS ()` isn't supported in MySQL syntax, I wonder what the equivalent syntax should be in MySQL Workbench? Thanks.

Below is a screenshot of the syntax error:
[image]

Comment: It is supported in MySQL. If you are using the old version 5.x of MySQL I would strongly suggest to upgrade.

Comment: @TheImpaler Hi I'm currently using MySQL Workbench v8.0, but I got error `Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'temp AS ( xxxxxx' at line 1`, I just uploaded a screenshot of the error in the question description.

Comment: You may be using MySQL Workbench 8.0, but that is only a client. The SQL syntax supported depends on the MySQL Server. You can check what version of the server with this query: `SELECT VERSION();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have MySQL 5.x and you need to adapt the query which contains CTE, then convert

```sql
WITH cte AS (cte query text)
SELECT ... 
FROM cte
...
```

to

```sql
SELECT ... 
FROM (cte query text) cte
...
```

If there is more than one CTE then perform this substitution with accuracy from latter CTE to former one (you may need to use multiple copies of some CTE subquery text - this is a norma).

Comment: Hi do you mean the version of MySQL Workbench? I'm using v8.0 not 5.x

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/ I'm using it to run the queries...

Comment: Ahhh thanks, I'm using `5.7.12 (MySQL Community Server)`, I tried the syntax you mentioned in the answer, it gave me a different error `Error Code: 1370. execute command denied to user 'xxx'@'%' for routine xxx.DATEADD'`, do you know what's going on here?

Comment: @Cecilia SQL Server code cannot be converted to MySQL code directly - too many differences in syntax. The dialect convertion is separate, sometimes quite complex, and sometimes even unsolvable, task. Create another question deal with the convertion, and post complete SQL to be converted.